# Flutter update property of class with variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and despite my research I can't find the answers. How to update the values ​​of a class according to a dynamic variable.

For example in my User class I want to update the salary of my User according to a map. How to call the key to update the class ?

My class :

```
class Users{
  List<User> user;

  Users({this.user});

  Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['user'] != null) {
      user= new List<User>();
      json['user'].forEach((v) {
        user.add(new User.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.user!= null) {
      data['user'] = this.user.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{${this.user}}';
  }
}

class User{
 
  String name;
  int gender;
  num salary;

  User(
      {this.name,
        this.gender,
        this.salary,
      });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name= json['name'];
    gender= json['gender'];
    salary= json['salary'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['gender'] = this.gender;
    data['salary'] = this.salary;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ '
        '${this.name},'
        '${this.gender},'
        '${this.salary},'
        '}';
  }

}
```

Here the function that calculate the new salary of my User and update this.

```
func_OrderedUsers(List<User> users)
{
  List<User> _UsersInOrder;
  if (users.length > 0)
  {
    users.forEach((user)
    {
      Map _params = {
        "salary" : func_CalculateNewSalary(user)
      };
      func_UpdateItem(user, _params);
    });
//... some code
}
```

And My function UpdateItem :

```
func_UpdateItem(var item, Map params)
{
  if(params != null){
    params.forEach((key, value)
    {
      if(value != null){
        // Here is my problem ! 
        // How to use the key variable ?
        item.salary = value; // If I write directly the parameter it works (salary)
      }
    });
  }
  return item;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current implementation?

Comment: I don't see how to replace salary property in my updateItem function by the key variable.

Comment: Could you clarify that? Do you want to use the key as the setter function to call?

Comment: I use my updateItem function like a general function so I can't write the property directly like salary for exemple. It's why I pass a Map _param with all the values that I want updated and use a foreach for update for all the values in my params Map. But if I do that the property becomes the key variable and I can't use it because if I put "item.key" it doesn't recognize key in the properties of my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is something that `dart:mirrors` would do. However, since you seem to be using flutter, this is not available for you to use.

Instead you'll have to manually map each key of your `Map` to a field in your object, just like in your `fromJson` constructor. You could add a method that does this within your class. Ex.

```dart
void updateFieldsFromMap(Map<String, dynamic> input) {
  if(input['name'] != null) name = input['name'];
  if(input['gender'] != null) gender = input['gender'];
  if(input['salary'] != null) salary = input['salary'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use factory

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return new  User(
      name: data['name'],
      gender: data['gender'],
      salary: data['salary'],
          
    );
 }
```